# Getting services on remote servers through powershell

Tags: powershell, service, export-to-csv

I've been trying to develop a powershell script to query a particular OU in AD and then get the services on each of those services including name, status, startmode, startname, description. I've gotten really close but not getting the results I expect.  Can someone help?

The problem is if I run the command for one server specifically, I get the results I want.  If I run for all servers in an OU it does not find any unique startnames (only the local accounts).  I want a single CSV with the server name first

**Script for single computer (getting results we want):**

```
$ServerName = “server01”

Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $servername | Select @{N="ServerName";E={$ServerName}}, Name, Status, StartMode, StartName, description | Export-Csv "server_Services.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Script for querying OU (only returning services with local accounts):**

```
$ServerOU = 'OU=Servers,DC=some,DC=domain'

$ServerList = Get-QADComputer -SearchRoot $ServerOU -SearchScope Subtree

$ServerList | ForEach {   
      $ServerNameTemp = $_.Name
      Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | 
      Select @{N="ServerName";E={$ServerNameTemp}}, StartName, Name, StartMode, Status, description
      } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $ExportFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick i think  but th following would wanna make a file for each server in the OU, it would keep overwriting the same file.
I also Changed Get-QADComputer into Get-ADComputer no specific need for quest powershell for this one :)

```
$ServerOU = 'OU=Servers,DC=some,DC=domain'

$ServerList = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $ServerOU  -Filter *

ForEach ($Server in $Serverlist)
{
          Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server.Name -ScriptBlock {
              Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | 
              Select @{N="ServerName";E={[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()}}, StartName, Name, StartMode, Status, description}
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $ExportFile
```

This way it would send ti all to a variable first and then to a file.

```
$ServerOU = 'OU=Servers,DC=some,DC=domain'
$Services = @()
$ServerList = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $ServerOU -Filter * 

ForEach ($Server in $Serverlist)
{
          $Services += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server.Name -ScriptBlock {
               Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | 
              Select-Object @{N="ServerName";E={[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()}}, StartName, Name, StartMode, Status, description }
} 

$Services | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $Exportfile
```

Comment: So much better but it is having troubles connecting to some servers.  Getting error messages: Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The client canno
t connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination i
s running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management servi
ce running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service,
 run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm qu
ickconfig".

Comment: I had to use QADComputer too, the ADComputer didn't work

Comment: Ahh, well if they are server 2003 they might not support the remote powershell conntection yet or something like that. Or remote powershell is disabled something like that.  in the end it doesnt really matter, Quest powershell returns the same as Regular PS i believe. I changed it simply cause I didnt wanna install quest powershell :P

Answer (score 0):

PS Remoting is automatically enabled from win 2012. If you are using any Win servers prior to that, you need to enable to WinRM services, to enable powershell remoting. This is very important, if you are trying to use "Invoke-Command" or any of those "*-Session" cmdlets against those servers.